# Making a drop down list using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, drop-down-menu

What is the library to make drop down menu in swift? I am new to Xcode and the Swift language, so can anyone please direct me on how to implement the drop down list in swift?

Comment: Check this link, it might help http://code4app.net/category/menu

Comment: try this https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8rflh1oygtcerh/single%20dropdown.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A 'drop down menu' is a web control / term. In iOS we don't have these. You might be better looking at `UIPopoverController`. Check out this tutorial for a bit of an insight to PopoverControllers

http://www.raywenderlich.com/29472/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uipopovercontroller-tutorial

Answer (score 39):

(Swift 3) Add text box and uipickerview to the storyboard then add delegate and data source to uipickerview and add delegate to textbox. Follow video for assistance
https://youtu.be/SfjZwgxlwcc

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textBox: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dropDown: UIPickerView!

    var list = ["1", "2", "3"]

    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{

        return list.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return list[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        self.textBox.text = self.list[row]
        self.dropDown.isHidden = true
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if textField == self.textBox {
            self.dropDown.isHidden = false
            //if you don't want the users to se the keyboard type:

            textField.endEditing(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately if you're looking to apply `UIPopoverController` in iOS9, you'll get a deprecated class warning. Instead you need to set your desired view's  `UIModalPresentationPopover` property to achieve the same result.

> **Popover**
>
> In a horizontally regular environment, a presentation style
>   where the content is displayed in a popover view. The background
>   content is dimmed and taps outside the popover cause the popover to be
>   dismissed. If you do not want taps to dismiss the popover, you can
>   assign one or more views to the passthroughViews property of the
>   associated UIPopoverPresentationController object, which you can get
>   from the popoverPresentationController property.
>
> In a horizontally compact environment, this option behaves the same as
>   UIModalPresentationFullScreen.
>
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621355-modalpresentationstyle

Comment: Thanks for pointing out deperecation of UIPopoverController

Answer (score 5):

You have to be sure to use UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate protocols or it will throw an AppDelegate error as of swift 3

Also please take note of the change in syntax:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
```

is now:

```
public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
```

The following below worked for me.

```
import UIkit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textBox: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dropDown: UIPickerView!

    var list = ["1", "2", "3"]

    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{

        return list.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return list[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        self.textBox.text = self.list[row]
        self.dropDown.isHidden = true
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if textField == self.textBox {
            self.dropDown.isHidden = false
            //if you don't want the users to se the keyboard type:

            textField.endEditing(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not talking about spinners or pickers but drop-down or pull down menu.

Answer (score 3):

Using ***UIPickerview*** is the right way to go to implement it according to Apple's Human Interface Guidelines

If you select drop down in mobile safari it will show ***UIPickerview*** to let the use choose drop down items.

Alternatively

you can use ***UIPopoverController*** till iOS 9 as its deprecated but its better to stick with ***UIModalPresentationPopover*** of view you want o show as well

you can use ***UIActionsheet*** to show the items but it's better to use ***UIAlertViewController*** and choose ***UIActionSheetstyle*** to show as the former is deprecated in latest versions