# How to create a drop down menu

Tags: swift

How can I create a menu like this using swift?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFBn5.png)

Comment: That is a `UIAlertController` using `.actionSheet`. Also this is not how SO works. You need to make an attempt to solve the problem yourself and post a question when you run into an issue. Please take a tour of SO . before asking questions. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a drop down list using swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319718/making-a-drop-down-list-using-swift)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's alertController with actionSheet. User this method in your button action for example.

```
func handleAlert()
  let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Change Profile Photo", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
  //First action
  alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Remove current photo", style: .destructive, handler: { (_) in
        // Your remove photo code here
    }))
  alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Import From Facebook", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
        // Your import from facebook code here
    }))
  //Cancel action
  alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
  present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```