# Creating dropdown in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to create a dropdown in swift, trying the following code:

```
import UIKit

class DataUser: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var btnDtop: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!

    var movinghouses = ["apple","coooasnk","scnaon","dojcncn"]

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func onClickDropButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }


}

extension DataUser : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return movinghouses.count
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = movinghouses[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

When I do, an error occurs in code, that states: "Thread 1: signal SIGABR".
How could I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a drop down list using swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319718/making-a-drop-down-list-using-swift)

Answer (score 0):

SIGABRT errors in this context are often the result of a broken connection between a UI element and an outlet. Try cleaning the project, and if that doesn't work check your UIButton's connections and make sure they haven't been changed or deleted. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546497/swift-error-signal-sigabrt-how-to-solve-it) or [this article](https://learnappmaking.com/sigabrt-xcode-swift/) for more information on how to do this.